# hololens emulator can't connect to sharing service

Tags: hololens, mrtk

I want to do something like academy 240, holograms sharing. Since I don't have two hololens,I want to test that between unity editor and emulator.  I try to do that using the latest MRTK, so some scripts are different.

1. I drag sharing prefab to hierachy form MRTK.
2. Then click Mixed Reality Toolkit->Sharing Service-> Launch Sharing Service and copy the IP address.
3. Paste the IP address to the Server Address of Sharing Stage(scripts attach to the sharing prefab)

Then, If I run in the unity editor, the SharingService shows message like:
SharingService: User VR at address 172.23.173.81 joined session DefaultSession

However, If I deploy this project to hololens emulator, nothing happened in SharingService. Does any other setting I need to do?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

For Hololens device and Emulator, you need to put the IP of your machine (seems to be `192.168.1.86` in your case).

Comment: Do you mean change the server address to 169.168.1.86 ？I tried,and still can't connect to the server.

Comment: @Mayoco Hi, were you able to address this issue? Currently stuck trying to connect the emulator to the sharing service too, but no issues with the Unity Editor connecting to the server.

Currently exploring the test scenes, particularly Sharing Test.